# iOS 14 beta 3 - Application screen not displayed on full screen

Tags: ios, swift, ios14

I have updated my iPhone X from iOS 13.6 to the iOS 14 beta 3.
Facing full screen issue for all applications installed on iPhone.
Currently black view is displayed at top and bottom of the screen.

Please see the attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OacWW.png) for the same.

Is there anything which we need to change to see the app full size screen?

Thanks in advance. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You faced this issue with only whats App or any other app?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Display & Brightness > View

and change it to `Standard` instead of `Zoomed`

This will change your view to a standard and normal view.

Hope this will help you resolve your issue.

Comment: That works, but... is there any information on how an app can display full screen also in zoom mode ?